# Magento 2.3.4: Is there an alternative tag to "area" to meet AMP requirements for my store home page

Tags: magento2.3.3, html, tags

Google Search Console identified the tag "area" in the HTML of our Magento store home page. The HTML is as seen below. Is there an alternative to this tag so as to fix the Accelerated Mobile Pages error search console pointed out?

```
<area title="TV Mirrors" alt="TV Mirrors" coords="1011,740,1262,785" shape="rect" href="/mirrors/tv-mirrors.html" target="_self">
 
<area title="Vanity Mirrors (lighted)" alt="Vanity Mirrors (lighted)" coords="250,86,555,139" shape="rect" href="/mirrors/lighted-vanity-mirrors.html" target="_self">
 
<area title="Backlit Mirrors" alt="Backlit Mirrors" coords="245,28,562,72" shape="rect" href="/mirrors/backlit-mirrors-category.html" target="_self">
 
<area alt="" coords="244,29,245,72" shape="rect">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since area tag is an old HTML tag without an AMP equivalent, I had to use an extension supplied by the third party whose theme is being applied to our Magento store. There are a bunch of extensions one can find on marketplace.